# Frequent Subgraph Mining for neo4j single graph

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I wanted to extract frequent subgraphs from my neo4j graph data ( single graph).
My input should be the neo4j graph data ( which can be extracted in graphml, cypher script and csv forms) for further processing and the output should be the most frequently occurring graphs based on the minimum and maximum support I provide.

I have already tried [this](https://github.com/fangjiegao/ssm_neo4j) implementation which is based on depth-search-first algorithm but would like also implement breath search first on the data for finding the graphs, as that would be more relevant for my task.

Are there any libraries for accomplishing the same?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Neo4j Graph Data Science](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/) library (GDS).

Perhaps one of the GDS [community detection](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/community/) algorithms will be of help.

Comment: Hi, Seems that an algorithm for frequent pattern search is not yet in the Neo4j Graph Data Science Catalog. Community Detection does not directly serve the purpose but it is a close workaround.